# How to get my eth0 up and running? I have tried all but none bring this up

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, network-manager, networking

Ubuntu 11.04. Why the eth0 gets down, is there no tools or script to bring it up?

I tried several way, but none worked. Any idea?

1) vim /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

2) ifup eth0

a)

```
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 1723
```

b) ifup eth0

```
ifup: interface eth0 already configured
```

3) restarted networkmanager but same no luck

**Follow up:**

```
1) sudo update-rc.d -f NetworkManager remove
2) sudo apt-get install dhcpcd
3) dhcpcd eth0
4) ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean, "when it gets down"?

NetworkManager and `/etc/network/interfaces` are two separate ways of controlling the network, you should use one or the other. If you use NetworkManager, the `interfaces` file should be empty (everything commented out for eth0).

`ifconfig -a` output may help. Can you ping your default gateway? Or anything at all?

Comment: I can not ping anything at-all. And my total interface lights goes down when Ubuntu starts.

Comment: Now, after login with LiveCD, i do not have Eth0 up either.

Comment: You should consolidate as much relevant information as possible into the original question, including this. Post hardware details, output of appropriate parts of dmesg (grep for eth0, perhaps).

Comment: `sudo dmesg | grep eth0`; is showing eth0: link becomes ready

Comment: Do i have to install "apt-get install dhcpcd"? What does that do.